# Reconciling multiple inorganic properties for the purposes of learning these elements

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, periodic-trends

How can I reconcile all of the chemical properties, physical properties and peculiar behaviour of metals in inorganic chemistry for the purposes of studying these systematically?

It is very hard to learn all of these for each group.

Comment: Well, trying to learn the physical properties of the elements is tough since there are >110 of them, and while the properties are periodic, the trends are not obvious. I hope you haven't been asked to memorize them. Given the easy access to online and text references to these properties, memorization seems like a poor use of your time.

Comment: Yes, i have been asked to memorize them. I have to write them in my exam.

Comment: People who gravitate towards chemistry as a career seem to have a larger ability than most to keep encyclopediac information in their heads.  Good luck if you're not one of us.

Comment: Working with formulas and properties of molecules helps definitely getting some of the most relevant info into your head, but keeping it there is a whole new blank page...

Comment: You can't 'remember', there is too many of them. Each one has its own quirks, so there is no simple way here. Lucky enough, it is not required: most common chemistry happens to deal with elements up to bromine, second and third row of d-element are very similar, and f-elements almost do not occur outside special cases. Lucky enough, even that is not usually required, as each individual chemist usually focus on specific narrow class of compounds of several or even one element, so only a very shallow general knowledge is required.

Answer (score 1):

first of all take one group a day.
right whatever you have to learn and then try to identify some relationship. Then reread the material and write down whatever you remember . Now look what you miss. 
everyday take a new group and do the same.
Also write whatever you remember of the previous groups you have learned.